# How to make window to be able to be thin in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

Why doesn't the following application allow me to make window very thin? The minimal width allows to layout 3 columns of images while I wish to make one-column-wide possible.

[image]

How to allow narrowing more?

```
package tests;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class TryRowLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RowLayout rowLayout = new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL);
        rowLayout.wrap = true;





        Display display = new Display();

        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        shell.setMinimumSize(1, 1);
        //shell.setLayout(rowLayout);

        Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        composite.setLayout(rowLayout);




        Image image = new Image(display, "images/alt_window_32.gif");

        Label label;
        for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
            //label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
            label = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
            label.setImage(image);
        }



        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is that Windows requires a minimal window width to be able to add the min/max/close buttons and the window title.

The default style of the `Shell` is

```
SWT.SHELL_TRIM = SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN | SWT.MAX | SWT.RESIZE
```

Unfortunately, you can't even get around this by forcing the `Shell` to just show the close button:

```
Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.RESIZE);
```

Windows will still enforce the minimal width.

---

Concluding, I'm afraid there is nothing you can do about it if you still require the window controls. If you don't need the window controls, then you can use

```
Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.RESIZE);
```

Here is example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    RowLayout rowLayout = new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    rowLayout.wrap = true;

    Display display = new Display();

    Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.RESIZE);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    shell.setMinimumSize(1, 1);
    // shell.setLayout(rowLayout);

    Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayout(rowLayout);

    Label label;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        // label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        label = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText("A");
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    shell.setSize(50, 200);
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
}
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]